# How do I change a &Path's first ancestor in Rust?

Tags: rust, path, ancestor

I want to change the first ancestor of a `&Path`, possibly by returning a new `PathBuf` like so.

```
fn change_parent(path: &Path, new_parent: &Path) -> PathBuf;
```

Here's how I expect it to work.

```
let old_path = change_root(Path::new("/hello/world.html"), Path::new("/html"));
let new_path = PathBuf::from("/html/world.html");
assert_eq!(old_path, new_path)
```

I tried `.ancestors()` but the `Path::new("/hello/world.html").ancestors();` returns an iterator over `["/hello/world.html", "/hello", "/"]` which is kind of the opposite of what I want. What I want is `["/hello/world.html", "hello/world.html", "/world.html"]` so I can append a new path easily.

Should I switch to using `split` on `"(/|\)"` then replacing the first result instead?

Comment: Have you had a look at [`Path::components`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.components)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using `strip_prefix` provided by conradludgate on The Rust Programming Language Community (Discord):

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf, StripPrefixError}; 

fn replace_prefix(p: impl AsRef<Path>, from: impl AsRef<Path>, to: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Result<PathBuf, StripPrefixError> {
  p.as_ref().strip_prefix(from).map(|p| to.as_ref().join(p))
}

(
  replace_prefix("/public/file.html", "/public", "/.html_output"),
  replace_prefix("/public/folder/nested/file.html", "/public", "/.html_output"),
  replace_prefix("/folder/nested/file.html", "/public", "/.html_output"),
)
```

```
(Ok("/.html_output/file.html"), Ok("/.html_output/folder/nested/file.html"), Err(StripPrefixError(())))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Path::components](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.components) I was able to come up with this solution:

```
use std::path::{Component, Path};
use std::{ffi::OsString, path::PathBuf};

let path = Path::new("/tmp/foo.txt");
let mut b: Vec<_> = path.components().collect();

// b[0] is the root directory "/" and b[1] is the
// "tmp" directory.
let html = OsString::from("html");
b[1] = Component::Normal(&html);

let pb: PathBuf = b.iter().collect();
```

I couldn't find a simpler way to do this.  The `Path` and `PathBuf` implementations are both based on a single `OsString`. So, with both types, to get access to individual components in the path, the underlying `OsString` would need to be split by something and `components` is the way to do the splitting. So, I don't think there's really another solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response! `components` is a useful API, but thanks to discord I'm now also aware of `strip_prefix` which is what I'm more interested in.